# How to query the inner HTML content in <mat-option> in typescript unit test

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the HTML block:

```
<mat-select ...>
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let option of options"
  >
    {{ option.text }}  // I want to query this.
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In my typescript unit test, I want to test against the content of `option.text`, I tried the following but neither worked:

```
// Prep.
const matSelect = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatSelect)).nativeElement;
matSelect.click();
fixture.detectChanges();

// Got error trying to access nativeElement of `null` from below:
fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatOption)).nativeElement.textContent

fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-option')).nativeElement.textContent

fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-option')).nativeElement.textContent
```

Comment: I think you should try like this : By.css('mat-option')

Comment: I've tried this as well, also got null, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`By.directive` does not work when querying `mat-select`.

```
const matSelect = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatSelect)).nativeElement;
matSelect.click();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

should be:

```
const matSelect = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-select')).nativeElement;
matSelect.click();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

You'll then be able to get text content:

```
    const text = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-option')).nativeElement.textContent;

    expect(text.trim()).toEqual("Steak");
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmgpqh-7ewwa4?file=src/app/select-overview-example.spec.ts)